# Can't get access to DB via phpmyadmin - docker

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I'm pretty new to docker and I guess I have made a proper beginner mistake here but I really can't get my head around of what's wrong...

I have sucesfully created a docker container with a running Wordpress installation. The link to the DB does work there. I can also access phpmyadmin but I can't get in. The following errors appear:

- Invalid hostname for server 1. Please review your configuration.
- Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

This is my `docker.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  my-wpdb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: letmein
  my-wp:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - my-wpdb:mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: letmein
  phpmyadmin:
    image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
    links:
        - my-wpdb:mysql
    ports:
        - 8181:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_USERNAME: letmein
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: letmein
```

I'm trying to log in with: **root, letmein**

Thank's! Any help appeciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your phpmyadmin is probably trying to connect to mysql using a different hostname from what you expect. (`localhost` probably?)

In your specific case [you need to set it to](https://github.com/corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin/blob/master/sources/config.inc.php#L38) use `my-wpdb`, more specifically you want to set that `$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR` to point to your database.

From the source code of that (deprecated) docker image is not quite clear, but I'm guessing you need to specify that with

```
  phpmyadmin:
    image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8181:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_USERNAME: letmein
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: letmein
        MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR: my-wpdb
```

Comment: Cheers! This did fix it! Any tips for a non depricated phpmyadmin package?

Comment: You can use the official docker image from the phpmyadmin repository instead: https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/

Comment: It's has an good readme file, that `corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin` lacks.